# Why is db_placeholder returning empty strings for my query?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using db_placeholder within a query to replace an array of strings.

```
$paths = array("commentary_analysis/18", "commentary_analysis/16", "commentary_analysis/95", "commentary_analysis/89");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, u.mail FROM {alerts} a JOIN {users} u on u.uid = a.uid WHERE u.mail IS NOT NULL AND u.mail != '' AND u.status = 1 AND a.status = %d AND a.view_path IN (" . db_placeholders($paths, 'text') . ") ORDER BY a.uid ASC";

$users_to_notify = db_query($query, $alert_status, $paths);
```

The query is not returning results, when I know it should.  I debugged the query to see the exact query that is getting run.  The query being run is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, u.mail FROM alerts a JOIN users u on u.uid = a.uid WHERE u.mail IS NOT NULL AND u.mail != '' AND u.status = 1 AND a.status = 1 AND a.view_path IN ('','','','') ORDER BY a.uid ASC
```

Notice, `a.view_path IN ('','','','')`.  That is the problem.  From what I can see, I expect that db_placeholder is getting used with the correct syntax.

Could someone tell me why my use of db_placeholder is returning `('','','','')` instead of `("commentary_analysis/18", "commentary_analysis/16", "commentary_analysis/95", "commentary_analysis/89")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you can either pass all single value arguments to db_query, or you can pass an array of arguments. Your code is passing a single value, and then an array, and Drupal just isn't that flexible.

Try this:

```
$paths = array(
  'commentary_analysis/18',
  'commentary_analysis/16',
  'commentary_analysis/95',
  'commentary_analysis/89',
);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, u.mail
          FROM {alerts} a
          JOIN {users} u on u.uid = a.uid
          WHERE u.mail IS NOT NULL
            AND u.mail != ''
            AND u.status = 1
            AND a.status = %d
            AND a.view_path IN (" . db_placeholders($paths, 'varchar') . ")
          ORDER BY a.uid ASC";

$args = array_merge(array($alert_status), $paths);
$users_to_notify = db_query($query, $args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the order of the db_query modifiers in the query fixes the problem.

```
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, u.mail FROM {ifrmarkets_alerts} a JOIN {users} u on u.uid = a.uid WHERE u.mail IS NOT NULL AND u.mail != '' AND a.view_path IN (" . db_placeholders($paths, 'varchar') . ") AND u.status = 1 AND a.status = %d ORDER BY a.uid ASC";
  $users_to_notify = db_query($query, $paths, $alert_status);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, db_placeholders is deprecated in Drupal 7, so you should consider not using it. It is memory wasting function.

Try using varchar data type:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT a.uid, u.mail FROM {alerts} a JOIN {users} u on u.uid = a.uid WHERE u.mail IS NOT NULL AND u.mail != '' AND u.status = 1 AND a.status = %d AND a.view_path IN (" . db_placeholders($paths, 'varchar') . ") ORDER BY a.uid ASC"
```

Comment: How else would you run a query with 'IN ("text", "text", "text")' in Drupal6 without using db_placeholders?  Why would you expect 'varchar' to work differently than 'text'?  Although I agree 'varchar' should get used, I wouldn't expect the behavior to be different if that is the only change I try.  I did try replacing with 'varchar' and had the same outcome.

Comment: 'text' should work fine, although 'varchar' is probably the proper type to use. The problem is passing in the arguments to the function.